# Adding properties dynamically to node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am experimenting with different ways to code a Node.js module and tried this:

**game.js**

```
    var board = require('./board'),
        player = require('./player');

    // setting module.exports to a function constructor so I can make instances of this node module from my test
    var game = module.exports = function(){};

    // dynamically add properties and set their default values
    // I don't think I need to use any prototypes here right?
    // And yes I realize I could use ES6 classes with an explicit constructor but that's a suggestion we can put on the side for now...
    game.initialize = function(){
        game.started = false;
        game.status = 'not started';
        game.board = board.create();

        return game;
    };

    game.start = function(){
        game.started = true
    };
```

**game-test.js**

```
let chai = require('chai'),
    should = chai.should(),
    game = require('../src/game');

describe('Game - Initial State', () => {
    var newGame;

    beforeEach((done) => {
        newGame = new game().initialize;
        done();
    });

    it('should contain a new board to play on', () => {
        should.exist(newGame.board);
    });
...
```

I'm getting the error `"Cannot read property 'board' of undefined"`

If I remove the .initialize() I get an instance of game but then no properties.  I'm not sure if this is even a good pattern but first would like to know what I'm doing wrong here.  And then any additional suggestions I'm open to hearing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Game.initialize` is a function.

In your test your are not calling the function, so your variable `newGame` is just a ref to `Game.initialize` instead of a `Game` instance

```
// your line
newGame = new game().initialize;
// should be
newGame = new game().initialize();
```

**Edit:** Also, you may want to use `this` instead of `game` in your `initialize()` function.